# NSWindow controlling multiple tabs

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nstabview, nstabviewcontroller

What is the best way to achieve multiple tab control within a single NSWindow akin to the Terminal App?

[image]

The existing TabView & TabViewController don't seem to be able to achieve this but I'm not sure.

My first thought was to use a collection view but I'm afraid to start re-inventing something already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually a magic that the operating system does for you with multiple windows.

You set the [`tabbingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1644729-tabbingmode?language=objc) of your window and a [`tabbingIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1644704-tabbingidentifier?language=objc) if needed. From there, the system will handle your tabbing needs. You create separate windows. If you want to force tabbing in your application, use the [`addTabbedWindow:ordered:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1855947-addtabbedwindow?language=objc) API.

You also get the "new tab" and "view all tabs" functionality for free.

Comment: When calling `addTabbedWindow:ordered:`, make sure the new window is part of the responder chain, e.g. set `newWindow.windowController` so it forwards `NSResponder` messages to the same controller as the original window.